# Rain Probability

Tags: probability

The probability of rain on any given day during December to March is 14/19 in the Fiji Islands.

a. What is the probability of no rain in 3 days?

$$P(\text{no rain in 3 days})=\binom{3}{0}(5/19)^3(14/19)^0$$
$$=0.0182$$

b. How many days n do you have to wait in order to be 99.9% sure of having rain by that day?

I am really unsure about how to go about this, but here's my attempt:

$$1 - \binom{n}{0}(5/19)^n(14/19)^0 \ge 0.999$$
$$n \ge log(0.001)/log(5/19)$$
$$n \ge 5.1743$$
so the answer is 6 days??

But I don't know how I can solve for n......or is there another approach to this? I would appreciate a push in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the meaning of the "1" your b. formula.. What is $X$, anyway?

Comment: @PeterFranek I guess I chose 1 because it said how many days to wait for a 99.9% chance of rain that day, so I chose 1 ...probably my logic isn't correct. Could you give me a hint about the right way to go about this then?

Comment: Well, if you choose 1, it correspond more to a situation "in the first $n$ days, exactly one day will rain.." This is not what you want. You want the probability that there will be no rain in $n$ days to be 1 percent or less.

Comment: I think your edited version of (b) is correct.  If you want to check, repeat the calculation in (a) for five days and for six days

Comment: @Henry oh good idea! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming independence of rain on different days, you should continue your answer to (a) to consider the probability that there are not $n$ dry days out of $n$ by setting  up $$1 - \binom{n}{0}(5/19)^n(14/19)^0 \ge 0.999$$ though the values of $\binom{n}{0}$ and $(14/19)^0$ can be easily taken into account  and the $1$ and $0.999$ can be combined.

To solve what remains, you need to use logarithms and then round up to the nearest integer above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just wondering if you could explain why I have to round up?

Comment: On your first question, if you found $n \ge 7.4$ (a wrong example) then $7$ days would be insufficient but $8$ days would be enough

Comment: Got it! Thanks~